# Java Error: class, interface, or enum expected (Pizza order program)

Tags: java, class, interface, enums

Working on a Pizza/Pizza order program in java and I keep getting 13 of the error: class, interface, or enum expected.  I know the problem should be with the curly brackets, but I haven't been able to find it.  I was hoping that a different set (or sets) of eyes would be able to spot the error(s).

```
public Pizza (String size, int cheese, int pepperoni, int ham) {
    this.size = size;

    if (cheese < 0) {
        this.cheese = 0;
    }
    else {
        this.cheese = cheese;
    }
    if (pepperoni < 0) {
        this.pepperoni = 0;
    }
    else {
        this.pepperoni = pepperoni;
    }
    if (ham < 0) {
        this.ham = 0;
    }
    else {
        this.ham = ham;
    }
}   

public double calcCost() {
    if (size.equals("small")) {
        return 10 + 2 * (ham + cheese + pepperoni);
    }
    else if (size.equals("medium")) {
        return 12 + 2 * (ham + cheese + pepperoni);
    }
    else if (size.equals("large")) {
        return 14 + 2 * (ham + cheese + pepperoni);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid size");
    }
}

public class PizzaOrder {
    private Pizza pizza1;
    private Pizza pizza2;
    private Pizza pizza3;

    public PizzaOrder() {
        numPizzas = 1;
        pizza1 = new Pizza();
        pizza2 = new Pizza();
        pizza3 = null;
    }

    public PizzaOrder (int numPizzas, Pizza pizza1, Pizza pizza2, Pizza pizza3) {
        this.numPizzas = numPizzas;
        this.pizza1 = pizza1;
        this.pizza2 = pizza2;
        this.pizza3 = pizza3;
    }

    public void setNumPizzas (int numPizzas) {
        if (numPizzas > 3) {
            this.numPizzas = 3;
        }
        else if (numPizzas < 1) {
            this.numPizzas = 0;
        }
        else {
            this.numPizzas = NumPizzas; 
        }
    }

    public void setPizza1 (Pizza pizza1) {
        this.pizza1 = pizza1;
    }

    public void setPizza2 (Pizza pizza2) {
        this.pizza2 = pizza2;
    }

    public void setPizza3 (Pizza pizza3) {
        this.pizza3 = pizza3;
    }

    public double calcTotal() {
        double total = pizza1.calcCost();

        if (numPizzas >= 2) {
            total += pizza2.calcCost();
        }

        if (numPizzas == 3) {
            total += pizza3.calcCost();
        }

        return total;
    }
}

public class MainMethodClassName {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza("large", 1, 0, 1);
        Pizza pizza2 = new Pizza("medium", 2, 2, 0);

        PizzaOrder order = new PizzaOrder();

        order.setNumPizzas(2);
        order.setPizza1(pizza1);
        order.setPizza2(pizza2);

        double total = order.calcTotal;

        System.out.println("First Pizza: ");
        System.out.println(pizza1.getDescription());
        System.out.println("Second Pizza: ");
        System.out.println(pizza2.getDescription());
        System.out.println("Total price: $" + total);
    }
}
```

The errors are in lines 1, 4, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, and 36

Thank you for the help; I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is this your whole source file? If so you have methods defined outside a class. Perhaps your class definition should be moved to the top of your file or you need another class definition.

Comment: `this.numPizzas = NumPizzas;` appears to have the wrong case on the right-hand side.

Comment: Your first two methods are not in a class.  You need to add `public class Pizza {` at the beginning, and add `}` before the next class begins.

Comment: And of course, you should really define each class in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are not your only problem.

```
public double calcCost() {
    if (size.equals("small")) {
        return 10 + 2 * (ham + cheese + pepperoni);
    }
    else if (size.equals("medium")) {
        return 12 + 2 * (ham + cheese + pepperoni);
    }
    else if (size.equals("large")) {
        return 14 + 2 * (ham + cheese + pepperoni);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid size");
    }
}
```

This won't compile as in the `else` you return nothing which is illegal when the return type is specified.

As for the brackets, since you give us line and suppose we should be able to count them correctly with the code you pasted. I believe you copied all this in one single file.

If that is true, then the problem is with the first two method which are not in a class, this is illegal in Java. Either put them in an other class, or add them to an already existing one if this is where they reside.

Also, you should not declare all classes in one single file even if this compile as this will be terrible to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Like he said. 
 When you build classes they should encapsulate an idea

Do

```
public class pizza{

public static pizzaSize(){
}
public static toppings(){
}
}
```

So on and so forth. If you don't make methods void then they have to have returns, also if you make them static then you can use them in main without instant katsina by calling "class.method()"